# transmission file selection with magnet links

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Is it possible to select which files to download with transmission-cli(or daemon) when using magnet links?

Maybe it is somehow possible to convert first to .torrent file and then continue with selected files?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your magnet link into a torrent using a service like [Magnet >> Torrent](http://magnet2torrent.com/). Once this is done, you just provide the torrent to Transmission and you can now select the files you want.

There is also the long standing [enhancement request #4808](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/4808) as well as [GitHub feature request #218](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/218) to provide the option to automatically pause the download *after* downloading the metadata. There is even a (probably outdated) patch but it has never been merged.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @scart

Answer (score 0):

not sure of the cli commands to throw but it is possible via gui but closest to same in transmission-daemon is

> transmission-daemon --paused ${remaining options}

this (per the man page)  will paused the entire d/l at start of D/L which would allow for a last minute 'white-listing' of torrent contents but not entirely sure how well using transmission-gtk as a reference this may be to you needs

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in BitTorrent, the magnet link doesn't point to the actual files downloaded; it points to the .torrent file only, so Transmission needs to download that first.

So this is certainly possible, but you need to wait until Transmission *downloads the file list*, then manually open the torrent's "Properties" window and select/deselect files there.

Comment: And is it possible to do this automiatically? Basically I want a script which downloads certain files from magnet link.